# Join and Separate Actions on Objects

Tags: modeling

I'm a 20+ yr Maya user and searched for a simple solution to separate, or "un-join" 2 previously joined objects. I found a few old posts (2+ yrs) that used hotkey commands that didn't work for me. Maybe because I'm using the Industry Standard UI option. Maybe because I'm using a newer version.

Anyway, here's the simple solution to separate 2 objects when you're ready. Move into editing mode and select a vertex on 1 of the objects. Use the up arrow until the entire single object is selected.
Mesh-Separate-Selection and they are back to separate objects.

Comment: Hello :). You can also post your solution as a full answer, so others coming from Maya can easily find it.

Comment: And by the way: *Mesh > Separate > Loose Parts* is also useful :).